# Assign random password to user on create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, passwords, assign

I have a user table in my database and what I wish to do is have a
random password generated for each user on create which is then sent to
their email address. I was wondering how I would assign the random
password.

I have the following in my view:

```
<p>
    <div id="p1"><%= t('.username')%></div>
    <%= f.text_field :username %>
</p>
<p>
    <div id="p1"><%= t('.email')%></div>
    <%= f.text_field :email %>
</p>
<p class="button"><%= f.submit 'Create Account' %></p>
```

The following in my controller:

```
def create
 @user = User.new(params[:user])
 respond_to do |format|
   if @user.save
    Notifier.user_created(@user).deliver
       format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully created.' }
       format.json { render json: @user, status: :created, location: @user }
    else
       format.html { render action: "new" }
       format.json { render json: @user.errors, status::unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

And I have the following in my user model:

```
attr_accessor :password
before_save :encrypt_password

def encrypt_password
    if password.present?
    self.password_salt = BCrypt::Engine.generate_salt
    self.password_hash = BCrypt::Engine.hash_secret(password, password_salt)
   end
end

def self.random_string(len)
    #generate a random password consisting of strings and digits
    chars = ("a".."z").to_a + ("A".."Z").to_a + ("0".."9").to_a password = ""
    1.upto(len) { |i| password << chars[rand(chars.size-1)]}
    return password
end

def self.authenticate(email, password)
    user = find_by_email(email)
    if user && user.password_hash == BCrypt::Engine.hash_secret(password, user.password_salt)
    user
 else
    nil
 end
end
```

I will have to remove my if password.present? line because it won't be present but I have the random string code, I just need to assign it to the hash/salt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def create
 @user = User.new(params[:user])
 @user.password = User.random_string(10) #set it with the size of the password you want
 respond_to do |format|
   if @user.save
    Notifier.user_created(@user).deliver
       format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully created.' }
       format.json { render json: @user, status: :created, location: @user }
    else
       format.html { render action: "new" }
       format.json { render json: @user.errors, status::unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

have fun!

Answer (score 1):

I suppose, you could just modify your encrypt_password ;)

```
before_save :encrypt_password

def encrypt_password
    self.password = User.random_string(X) unless password.present?
    self.password_salt = BCrypt::Engine.generate_salt
    self.password_hash = BCrypt::Engine.hash_secret(password, password_salt)
end
```

EDIT: if you want to encrypt the password only on create, you could use 'before_create' instead of 'before_save'